# How do I select a random row from database in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, select, random

I am trying to make a simple Quiz Application in Grails. I am having problem that i need to select a random row from the question table and display, and each time the user submits the answer, the question must be different.
I am new to grails...

I have a controller class named QuizController.groovy
and in controller, i have 
playQuiz() which should render a gsp page named playQuiz.gsp with one question at a time.

My domain for question is Question which have following
int id
    String question
    String answer1
    String answer2
    String answer3
    String answer4
    int correctAnswer

In database there may be numbers of rows populated with the datas, and i need to take one data at a time in random.

I need help with the data fetching from database in random order.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, I just edited the question. I hope it will be clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, was tested with Grails 2.5.3:

```
def randomQuestion = Question.find("from Question order by rand()")
```

Comment: you will get a list of questions here

Comment: Yes, It actually worked.but got as list element, displayed in this way [value].

Comment: The code was edited, this should return a domain object instead of list

Answer (score 0):

It is not very difficult. Hibernate `Criteria` has methods to specify the first result index: [setFirstResult(int firstResult)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFirstResult-int-) and max rows count: [setMaxResults(int maxResults)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults-int-).

```
int rowsCount = getRowsCount();
int randomRowIndex = getRandomNumberLessThan(rowsCount);

criteria.setFirstResult(randomRowIndex);
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```

You can use `HQL` as well

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Question");
query.setFirstResult(randomRowIndex);
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

And you need to use additional restrictions to not ask a question that was asked before.